# Text stretches outside cell boundaries on delete slide

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

A tableView cell of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle will truncate text.
Also, a regular UITableCell of multiple lines will truncate text if the delete slide is used.

However, my UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cell of mulitple lines doesn't truncate the text when delete slide comes in. Instead, it stretches outside the boundaries of the cell. Can I fix this? Here is some of my code ...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SwitchCell"];

if (cell==nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cellType"] autorelease];
    // set the labels to the appropriate text for this row
    cell.textLabel.text = [(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]groupName];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    if ([(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]isDynamic]){
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"dynamic", @"dynamic");
    }
    else {
        //get and set the group size
        int groupSize = [(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]groupSize];

        if (groupSize == 1)
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"1Contact", @"1 contact");
        else
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%dContacts", @"%d contacts"), groupSize];
    }     
}

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self tableView: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGFloat width = frame.size.width;

int section = indexPath.section;

NSString *title_string = cell.textLabel.text;
NSString *detail_string = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

CGSize title_size = {0, 0};
CGSize detail_size = {0, 0};

if (title_string && [title_string isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    title_size = [title_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0]
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000)
                              lineBreakMode:cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];
}

if (detail_string && [title_string isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    detail_size = [detail_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000)
                                lineBreakMode:cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode];
}

CGFloat title_height = title_size.height;
CGFloat detail_height = detail_size.height;

CGFloat content_size = title_height + detail_height;

CGFloat height;

switch ( section ) {

    case 0:
        height = content_size;
        break;

        //Just in case  
    default:
        height = 44.0;
        break;

}

return height;

}
```

Comment: What version are you deploying to? Simulator or Device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was so tough to work out! The problem is that it will always stretch the text if numberOfLines is set to 0. Therefore, I needed to calculate the numberOfLines, and set it for each cell.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = textLabelheight/textLabelFontSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your labels size, that would be your MAX width, like this:

```
cell.textLabel.frame.size.width = someWidth;

cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width = someWidth;
```

Comment: This truncates the text when the screen loads, but doesn't stop the text from stretching above and below the cell borders when the delete button slides in.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that i cannot understand what you mean, maybe you should change your height too, if i understood you correctly

Comment: I have fixed this issue now thanks. (I will tick my correct answer in a few hours when stack overflow lets me.) However, I have a new, related problem which I have risen a new question for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451405/text-in-cell-truncates-on-rotate