# Text in cell truncates on rotate! (edit: also cells screw up on scroll)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, orientation

**The problem:**

I have a UITableViewCell which word wraps the text when it first appears, but if you rotate to landscape and back to portrait again, the text has been truncated! Why is this or how can I fix it?

**Extra Detail:**

My cell is of style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. In order to wordwrap the text (the textLabel of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, not the detailTextLabel), I calculate how many lines high the text is, and set this via

```
 cell.textLabel.numberOfLines
```

I cant simply set numberOfLines to 0, cos when the delete button slides in, it looks ugly. This is explained in a previous question of mine: [Text stretches outside cell boundaries on delete slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426908/text-stretches-outside-cell-boundaries-on-delete-slide)

I set the height of the label via heightForRowAtIndexPath, but this is probably not the problem, because if i hard code this to a massive height, the text will still truncate after the orientation rotation.

**Edit:**

Since writing this I have noticed that my reuseIdentifier string wasn't the same when i tried to reuse the cell. Fixing this has improved the situation, and sometimes now the cells are fine. However, sometimes they still truncate on rotation, and also, if i scroll down and up again (so the cells are reload), they can truncate or change there height!

**Code:**

```
//This is a call back invoked by the interface when drawing the table view. This method will create a cell for each
//row and add text to each cell depending on the string retrieved from the datasource.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SwitchCell"];
CGFloat textLabelFontSize = 19;

if (cell==nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cellType"] autorelease];
    // set the labels to the appropriate text for this row
    cell.textLabel.text = [(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]groupName];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textLabelFontSize];

    if ([(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]isDynamic]){
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"dynamic", @"dynamic");
    }
    else {
        //get and set the group size
        int groupSize = [(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]groupSize];

        if (groupSize == 1)
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"1Contact", @"1 contact");
        else
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%dContacts", @"%d contacts"), groupSize];
    }
}

//Calculate height (so we can hard code the number of lines, which is neccesary to avoid ugly stretching when the delete button slides in)
CGFloat width = [[self table] frame].size.width-cell.indentationWidth-50;


int section = indexPath.section;

NSString *title_string = cell.textLabel.text;
NSString *detail_string = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

CGSize title_size = {0, 0};
CGSize detail_size = {0, 0};

if (title_string && [title_string isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    title_size = [title_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:textLabelFontSize]
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000)
                              lineBreakMode:cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];
}

if (detail_string && [title_string isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    detail_size = [detail_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000)
                                lineBreakMode:cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode];
}

CGFloat title_height = title_size.height;
CGFloat detail_height = detail_size.height;

CGFloat content_size = title_height + detail_height;

CGFloat height;

switch ( section ) {

    case 0:
        height = content_size;
        break;

        //Just in case  
    default:
        height = 44.0;
        break;

}

//hard code numberOfLines, to avoid ugly stretching when delete slides in
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = title_height/[UIFont systemFontOfSize:textLabelFontSize].lineHeight;
//set height for retrieval later if neccesary
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, height);

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self tableView: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: You can send notification on change of orientation and change the width according to orientation mode if you want.

Comment: I have edited my question to show I have half fixed the problem, but not fully. My fix implies that the issue is more to do with the reuse of cells when they dissappear and reappear from view. However, whether the scrolling issue and the orientation issue is the same or different issue, I dont know yet.

Comment: When your screen appears first, your text appears to fit in the cell. Right? If so, you definitely have orientation issue.

Comment: As far as screen orientation goes, I think the issue may be fixed now. I think the issue I now have is to do with if i do some scrolling. In fact this is very possibly a separate issue which I need to research or raise a new question for (?). If so, I will answer this question properly myself when stack overflow allows me to.

Comment: Aha! I have worked out when it goes wrong. (Bare in mind this is now I have partly fixed the problem using cell reuse). I have 3 cells in portrait mode which are fine. Then i go to landscape mode, and cell 3 is out of sight. If I scroll the cell up into sight, then rotate back to portrait mode, the text is truncated. The width and height of the cell looks fine tho.

Comment: This is what I was talking about. You need to take care about the height and width of views when you change your orientation.

Comment: Mmm yes. If in landscape, the text is 4 lines long, then when i go back to portrait it will assume it is still 4 lines long, but it should be 6. It is not recalculating when the orientation changes. Therefore it truncates. However, if i then scroll the cell out of sight and back again, it word wraps again. So, either I need to fiddle more with cell reuse so portrait cells are different to landscape cells (i dont know if thats possible), or I need to reload it somehow when the orientation changes. In other words, I need to simulate what it does when the cell scrolls out of sight and back.

Comment: Can you handle orientation change. If not I can provide code for handling it.

Comment: And yes you need to reload the table on changing the orientation.

Comment: I have shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, and I have tried doing [table reload] in there, but it fails to work. Somehow I need to simulate whatever it does when a cell scrolls out of sight and back (cos that makes the cell look right)

Comment: I have submitted an answer. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment in time, the following code appears to work on my device, but not on the simulator. Most testing needs doing though. The key fix is in the reuse of the cell, and probably [table reloadData]

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
[table reloadData];
return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[table reloadData];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

//This is a call back invoked by the interface when drawing the table view. This method will create a cell for each
//row and add text to each cell depending on the string retrieved from the datasource.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString * identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SwitchCell %d", indexPath.row]; // The cell row

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
CGFloat textLabelFontSize = 19;

if (cell==nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    // set the labels to the appropriate text for this row
    cell.textLabel.text = [(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]groupName];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textLabelFontSize];

    if ([(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]isDynamic]){
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"dynamic", @"dynamic");
    }
    else {
        //get and set the group size
        int groupSize = [(Group*)[composeData objectInChosenGroupsListAtIndex:indexPath.row]groupSize];

        if (groupSize == 1)
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"1Contact", @"1 contact");
        else
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%dContacts", @"%d contacts"), groupSize];
    }
}


CGFloat width = [[self table] frame].size.width-cell.indentationWidth-50;

int section = indexPath.section;

NSString *title_string = cell.textLabel.text;
NSString *detail_string = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

CGSize title_size = {0, 0};
CGSize detail_size = {0, 0};

if (title_string && [title_string isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    title_size = [title_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:textLabelFontSize]
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000)
                              lineBreakMode:cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];
}

if (detail_string && [title_string isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    detail_size = [detail_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000)
                                lineBreakMode:cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode];
}

CGFloat title_height = title_size.height;
CGFloat detail_height = detail_size.height;

CGFloat content_size = title_height + detail_height;

CGFloat height;

switch ( section ) {

    case 0:
        height = content_size;
        break;

        //Just in case  
    default:
        height = 44.0;
        break;

}

//hard code numberOfLines, to avoid ugly stretching when delete slides in
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = title_height/[UIFont systemFontOfSize:textLabelFontSize].lineHeight;
//set height for retrieval later if neccesary
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, height);

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self tableView: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Now implement the following method :

```
-(void)checkOrientation
{
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    [tblView reloadData];  
    // Set numberOfLines = some value you think might adjust the text.
    // Set x coorinate of views if you want to change

}
else
{
    [tblView reloadData];
    // Set numberOfLines = some value you think might adjust the text.
    // Set x coordinates of views to initial x xoordinates.

}

}
```

Create **recievedRotate** :

```
- (void)receivedRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
[self checkOrientation];
}
```

In **viewDidLoad** :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{  
[self checkOrientation];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but either I don't know what i need to put inside checkOrientation, or we have a slight misunderstanding. Bare in mind that I don't think the issue is with the physical size (width or height) of the cell or textLabel. Rather, I think the issue is with the numberOfLines value of the label. I'm not sure I would be able to access cell.textLabel.numberOfLines in the methods of your code. If you look in my code, this gets calculated in cellForRowAtIndexPath. However, I think my problem is that it seems to be setting the landscape numberOfLines when i change back to portrait.

Comment: Just fix the numberOfLines=2 or a maximum value you think will adjust your text in extreme case. In check orientation you can change the size of table or a view which is causing disturbance. You need to reload data in both conditions. Don't forget that.

Comment: Nitish! I cant believe how simple that was! Changing the numberOfLines to a big max number worked brilliantly! :S I'll test it some more soon and give you a giant green tick if its good! (or maybe post a new answer that says that, if u like, because this current answer isn't correct).

Comment: Hold on! No. I got far too excited too quickly! This causes the text to expand out of the cell when I slide in the delete button. This is an issue i had before, which i fixed by working out the correct number of Lines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426908/text-stretches-outside-cell-boundaries-on-delete-slide . I therefore still believe that I need to ensure that portrait and landscape calculate the correct number of lines.

Comment: You can set numberOfLines in both orientations. In potrait set it equal to say 1 and in landscape set it say 2.

Comment: Ive debugged through my code, and number of lines is getting set correctly. (2 in portrait, 1 in landscape.) However, the text still truncates on orientation change. However, if i scroll the cell down out of sight, and back into sight, no truncation occurs. So, what is being running when the scroll occurs which isn't when the orientation changes? And how can I call it? (p.s, my code in my question has changed now since im using cell reuse. Maybe i should post it?)

Comment: I think I just forgot one thing. Call checkOrientation in viewWillAppear too. Because it is the method which is called when you go to a view, either back or forth. Also don't forget to reload the table. If still you face some problem, post your code.

Comment: In this situation should I paste my current code over my original question, or in addition to my original question? (a few lines have changed at the start)

Comment: Make a section **UPDATE** and post it there. But post the complete code.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work okay now on my device, but not on the simulator. I will post my relevant code as an answer, but continue to test it. Many thanks for all your help up to now tho! And because its not yet fixed on the simulator, maybe there is still more comments to be made! and maybe it doesnt work on all iPhones?

Comment: I develop applications on both Android and IPhone. I have surely noticed one thing. How things appear on your Android emulator are entirely similar to when they appear on the Android device. Whereas in case of IPhone, it is not true. This is the reason why in case of IPhone it is advised to run the application on both simulator as well as device. You can't be sure.

Comment: Very good comment. I too found no problems like this on Android, but have learnt my lesson just now with iPhone! Nevertheless, some code changes I have been doing this morning were neccesary! I have posted my code (and potential correct answer) as an update to my question, because I cant make it an answer for the next 4 hours.